# 2 Access Point in Long Floor - [Device Prefer Problem]

Tags: cisco, router, network-core, access-point

We have 2 pcs Cisco WAP300N and working on Access Point mode.
This devices setted in a long floor. Also LAN cable connected to each one. And SSID's are the same.

Problem;

When someone starts to walk from begining of floor, connected first one normally. But when he reaches end of the floor, Mobile devices does not connect nearest and strong one (means 2nd one), it's stil triying to access the first one via poor signal.

Therefore, everybody living some stability issues with internet applications. We are living low signal level and some rupture problems.

Why these devices does not prefer nearest one ?

How can we configurate access point that WAP300N for continuous and smooth internet access.

[image: This is from WAP300N panel]
[image: This is from WAP300N panel]

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Turn access point transmit power down.**

If the client can't hear the "wrong" access point, it will connect to the right one. If it hears both and is prone to making bad choices (as many clients are) you get the problem you have. If clients can hear the wrong access point when they are near the "right" one, the wrong one (probably both) is (are) turned up too high.

Most people seem to gravitate to a "more power is better" approach to WiFi, which is pretty much the opposite of the truth. Lower power APs, closer to the clients (which may mean more APs) work better in nearly all cases...

...And run wired network to both APs - "Wireless Range Extender" is a performance-limiting mode that should be avoided. Good wireless is done with a lot of wire and fiber providing network to APs.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the client to determine when to roam from one AP to another.  The AP does not make the decision.

You can try disabling low data rates on the APs to encourage roaming, but ultimately, there's not a lot you can do.